# merge bookmark files with Python 3 pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I've downloaded an older Python 3 script which should be able to merge bookmark files.
But this line always produces an error.
Unfortunately I am absolute beginner in Python and I am also confused by pyparsing docs.

```
#using a private attribute of ParseResults to associate rows with hyperlinks
hyperlinks = dict([(pos,href) for href,pos in parseresults._ParseResults__tokdict.get('HyperLink',[])])
```

error:

```
hyperlinks = dict([(pos,href) for href,pos in parseresults._ParseResults__tokdict.get('HyperLink',[])])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Searched in the internet, but this is very special topic.

Comment: try print the parse result, `print(parseresults._ParseResults__tokdict)` and update your questions with this result. thanks

Comment: Can you include a link to where you downloaded this code from? Having more of the code to look at will be very helpful, and posting the link will be better than you pasting all the code here. In general, accessing internal fields like `__tokdict` is heavily discouraged (not a criticism of you, but of the source you downloaded the code from). Pyparsing's API _does_ take some getting used to, so that is natural for new Python people to puzzle over it. But just looking at what you posted, I think the API supports some better ways to get at the parsed results than accessing `__tokdict` directly.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/bookmark_merger/0.2.4/#files

But I think this was made for pyparsing 2.0.x and not for new pyparsing 3.0.x

Comment: Can you use a 2.x version of pyparsing?  2.4.7 is the latest stable release. It is also Python-2-compatible.

Comment: When I user pyparsing 3.x.x and make a dump I see some infomation.
So I think it should be possible to get out the needed information:

Comment: When I user pyparsing 3.x.x and make a dump I see some infomation.
So I think it should be possible to get out the needed information:
 
print (parseresults.dump())
  [4]:
    ['<DT><H3LAST_MODIFIED="1643">Linux</H3>', '<DT><A HREF="http://www.linux.de/" ADD_DATE="1388180518" LAST_MODIFIED="1643140443">Linux.de</A>', '<DT><A HREF="http://de.opensuse.org/Spiegelserver_der_stabilen_Version#.C3.96sterreich" A
    - Folder: 'Linux'
    - HyperLink: ['http://www.linux.de/', 'http://de.opensuse.org/Spiegelserver_der_stabilen_Version#.C3.96sterreich', 'http://de.opensuse.org/
  [5]:

Comment: I downloaded the files from the link you posted, but I don't see the problem line anywhere. Try changing that line to `hyperlinks = {pos: ref for href, pos in (parseresults.Hyperlink or [])}`